# Optimality of linear sum of two functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

If $x^* = \operatorname{argmin} f_i(x) \forall i$ then $x^* = \operatorname{argmin} (\sum k_i f_i(x)) $, For any $k_i \geq 0$. Is the converse true? Note that $f_i(x) $ are sequences and $x^*$ is merely the index for somplicity. note that converse can be easily proven for function of continuous variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given continuous functions, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ defined over $x \in D$, let, $f(x) = k_1 g(x) + k_2 h(x)$. $k_1, k_2$ are $\geq 0$. Now, for optima, $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$. And let, $x^* = \arg \min f(x), \forall k_1,k_2 \geq 0$. Then, $k_1g'(x^*) + k_2h'(x^*) = 0$. And then, $g'(x^*) = 0$ and $h'(x^*) = 0$. Or in other words, g(x) and h(x) are independently at their local optima at $x = x^*$.

Next, assume, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are sequences. If, $x^* = \arg \min g(x) =\arg \min h(x)$, and $k_1, k_2 \geq 0$. $\implies$ $x^* = \arg \min k_1 g(x) = \arg \min k_2 h(x)$. $\implies x^* = \arg \min k_1 g(x) + k_2 h(x)$.

Now we have to prove whether the converse is true.

We know, $x^* = \arg \min k_1 g(x) + k_2 h(x)$, where, $k_1, k_2 \geq 0$. Now, by setting $k_1 = 0$, and $k_2 = 0$ successively, we get, $x^* = \arg \min k_1 g(x) + k_2 h(x) = \arg \min g(x) = \arg \min h(x)$.